# echoing data from mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display data from my database table selected from a 'date'.
The query executes, but when I echo I don't get any result. Could you please help me with this?

```
<?php include 'includes/connection.php'; ?>
<html>
<head>
<title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dagtaken WHERE datum = $_POST[datum]";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['aantal'];
}
}else{
?>
<form action='' method='POST'>
<p><input type="date" name="datum"></p>
<p><input type='submit' value='Dagtaak toevoegen' />
<input type='hidden' value='1' name='submitted' /></p>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice [SQL injection vulnerability](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Stay as far away from mysql methods as possible. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Do you get any warnings or error messages in your code?

Comment: Also if you need to debug your code what about printing variable contents? try to put this in the cycle `var_export($row);`

Comment: Fixed my code, also I skipped the escape string on purpose, got it inserted now. Thanks. Also this "website" im building is for personal use only so I'm not too worried about security issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query shouldn't execute, since dates are very obviously strings and require quotes. That said...

[image: xkcd]

Try this:

```
mysql_query("SLEECT * FROM `dagtaken` WHERE `datum`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['datum'])."'");
```

Now on to the actual problem, you are checking `if(isset($_POST['submitted']))`, but nowhere do I see `<input name="submitted"` in your source (**EDIT** Never mind, it has a stupid amount of whitespace pushing it off the edge). Try `if(isset($_POST['datum']))`, since that's the variable you actually use.

Comment: Also he could simply check `if(isset($_POST))` ?

Comment: `$_POST` is set even if the request is `GET`. It'll be an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't named your submit button, so your PHP code never kicks in. Don't check for form fields when all you really need is to check if a POST has occured.

Quick fix for you code:

```
<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Dagtaak toevoegen" />
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Better fix:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    your code here ...
}
```

Comment: He has hidden input called `"submitted"`

Answer (score 0):

First, Escape your data. SQL injection is now very easy

Second, do you have data in your database?
Try print_r($row) instead of echo $row...

$_POST is with quotes...=> $_POST["datum"]
Last addition, is your date the same as your input?

Comment: I know I should escape my string first, but I skipped that because I wanted to get it working first. Inserted the escape string, thanks for your answer.